# The translation of 'at' in Spanish

Tags: gramática, preposiciones

The Spanish translation of

> He appears **at** night.

are given below. Is it correct both to say

> Él aparece **en** la noche.

and/or

> Él aparece **a** la noche.

`en` and `a`, what is the difference between the use of them?

Comment: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/15849/10864 may assist.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think both forms could be understood as correct, but a Spanish speaker would actually favor the prepositions `por` and `de`

> Él aparece **de** noche. La Luna sale de noche.
>
> Él aparece **por** la noche. La Luna sale por la noche.

It is correct to say

> ... **a** la noche.

You can use the preposition [`a` + noun](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=ctMgM8Bp2D6ELPuNfg) to designate parts of the day.

> a la mañana, a la tarde, a la noche.

You can also use

> ... **en** la noche

since the preposition `en` is used to indicate the time, place or way in which the action of the verb it goes with (in this case `aparecer`) was performed. But, again, prepositions `de` and `por` work better for this example.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to say:

> Él aparece a la noche

and

> Él aparece en la noche

but could also say `por` and `de`

> Él aparece de la noche.
>
> Él aparece por la noche

because usually people say `por la noche`, `por la manana`, and `por la tarde`. People also say `de la noche`

Hope this helps!! :)

Comment: "Él aparece **a noche**" is wrong. Should be "Él aparece a **la** noche" or "Él apareció (past) [anoche](http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=h4QE3sVlEDXX2bjW4hQU)" (one single word). The same way, it should be "Él aparece en **la** noche". You need the article.

Comment: Forgot to add it!!! Will add it!